# Json parse javascript : String displayed as NAN

Tags: javascript, json

So I am trying to parse a JSON file. I am using an alert to get the value of a particular field, but whenever I pass this particular string it is displayed as NaN:

```
myjsondata=JSON.parse(json);
alert(myjsondata.result.parameters.College-name);
```

Json file

```
`{
  "id": "1",
  "timestamp": "2017-05-11T04:03:26.008Z",
  "lang": "en",
  "result": {
    "source": "agent",
    "resolvedQuery": "hi",
    "action": "input.welcome",
    "actionIncomplete": false,
    "parameters": {
       "College-name": "Apex Technical School"},
    "contexts": [],
    "metadata": {
      "intentId": "b11a9493-7c2f-47c0-9928-5653a10c86e9",
      "webhookUsed": "false",
      "webhookForSlotFillingUsed": "false",
      "intentName": "Default Welcome Intent"
    },
    "fulfillment": {
      "speech": "Hi welcome from webfocus Api Ai",
      "messages": [
        {
          "type": 0,
          "speech": "Hi welcome from webfocus Api Ai"
        },
        {
          "type": 0,
          "speech": ""
        }
      ]
    },
    "score": 1
  },
  "status": {
    "code": 200,
    "errorType": "success"
  },
  "sessionId": "04737548-a3ff-485d-af1a-304edfee9486"
}`
```

Alert with action and other fields are working fine. But for college it is displayed as NAN.

Comment: As shown it json (`"parameters": {}`),`parameters` is empty

Comment: `"parameters": {}` doesnt have any key called `College-name`.

Comment: Because your `parameters` is empty.

Comment: Please also correct object key, it should be:
`alert(myjsondata.result.parameters['College-name']);`

Comment: Note that `College-name` is not a valid identifier, so you must use it with square bracket notation.

Comment: `myjsondata.result.parameters.College-name` ... is interpreted as subtracting `name` from `myjsondata.result.parameters.College`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting a null value because `parameters` does not have a key called `College-name`:

```
"parameters": {},
```

Also, you might want to change your selection be using:

```
alert(myjsondata.result.parameters['College-name']);
```